# Go directly to the nth find hit

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I want to go directly to the nth find hit in a document.

For example if I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type in `foo` and get 109 hits, how can I go directly to foo 42?

I know I can push <kbd>F3</kbd> 42 times, but I'm concerned I'd lose count.

Is there some shortcut, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> for "Goto Line"? Or some other way?